Two dimensional cylinder
I am reading a paper referring a two dimensional cylinder, if i understand the definition is
2d cylinder= $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z}$
What's the intuition behind this? Does anyone have a reference for a 2D cylinder?

No, $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Z}$ is not a cylinder. You probably meant the quotient by a suitable action of $\mathbb Z$ on the plane.

yes you are right, sorry, i will change it

Are you familiar with Pacman?

Yes, i think i am
